# Problema al imprimir matrices psint

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

No se si sea posible hacerlo de esta manera, pero cuando finalmente el programa va a imprimir las matrices se imprimen dos veces el nombre con ambas edades que he puesto

```
Dimension nombre[1, 2]
Dimension edad[1, 2]
Para i<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para m<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Escriba el nombre de la persona que se guardara en la celda ", i, ".", m
        Leer nombre[i, m]
    Fin Para
Fin Para

Para s<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para t<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Escriba la edad de la persona que se guardara en la celda ", s, ".", t
        Leer edad[s, t]
    Fin Para
Fin Para

Para i<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para m<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Para s<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Para t<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Escribir nombre[i, m], " tiene una edad de ", edad[s, t]
            Fin Para
        Fin Para
    Fin Para
Fin Para
```

FinAlgoritmo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en el momento de imprimir estas usando 4 ciclos, por eso te lo repite, solo neceitas dos ciclos ya que el pimero y el tercero solo hacen un solo ciclo, no son necesarios

Comment: prueba asi... `Para s<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Para t<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                Escribir nombre[s, t], " tiene una edad de ", edad[s, t]
            Fin Para
        Fin Para`

Comment: me ha funcionado muchas gracias. tengo una pregunta ¿por que en en ambas matrices se pone solo s y t? ¿el programa ya da por sentado a quien le pertenece cada edad basandose en las filas y las columnas?

Answer (score 0):

prueba asi...

```
Para s<-1 Hasta 1 Con Paso 1 Hacer 
  Para t<-1 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer 
   Escribir nombre[s, t], " tiene una edad de ", edad[s, t] 
  Fin Para Fin Para
Fin Para Fin Para
```

lo que sucede es que las letras hace parte solo de los iteradores, en las cuales su funcion lo unico que haces es recorrer las matrices, por ende las dos matrices tienen las mismas dimensiones,entonces solo son necesarios dos ciclos, es mas con dos ciclos ubieras podido rellenar las matrices, me alegra que te sirviera